# window.dnnLoadScriptsInAjaxMode undefined in page administration module

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, client-dependency

I have a problem with my development machine dotnetnuke installation. When I try to load the content of the page administration module under "Admin / Page Management", I get a JavaScript error

> pages:2089 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Wich is because window.dnnLoadScriptsInAjaxMode is undefined

```
var loadScriptInMultipleMode = function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < window.dnnLoadScriptsInAjaxMode.length; i++){
```

When I look into the page code I can see and debug that the following if check fails: "item.indexOf('$crm_')" is not working.

```
(function($){
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoading(function (sender, args){
var dataItems = args.get_dataItems();
for(var item in dataItems){
    if(item.indexOf('$crm_') > -1){
        var content = dataItems[item];
        ...
```

Because dataItems contains all values for the ClientDependency placeholders with underscore "_" as a prefix. e.g "_crm_BodySCRIPTS" instead of dollar sign "$" "$crm_BodySCRIPTS", which is what the code expects.

In our production instance everything is working fine and I can not remember changing any prefix configuration for the ClientDependency Framework. Combining and minifying files is turned of as in the Administration.

Can anybody help with what could be wrong here?

UPDATE:
I can see in Github Line:172 https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/development/DNN%20Platform/DotNetNuke.Web.Client/Providers/DnnBodyRenderProvider.cs that this is hardcoded. So I must have somehow already set a ScriptManager without knowing.

How can this be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by setting the clientIDMode attribute in web.config for pages.

```
<pages validateRequest="false" enableViewStateMac="true" enableEventValidation="true" viewStateEncryptionMode="Never"  clientIDMode="AutoID">
```

As the description from [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) states:

> The ClientID value is generated by concatenating the ID values of each parent naming container with the ID value of the control. In data-binding scenarios where multiple instances of a control are rendered, an incrementing value is inserted in front of the control's ID value. Each segment is separated by an underscore character (_). This algorithm is the only one that was available in versions of ASP.NET earlier than ASP.NET 4.

The attribute causes the change of $ to underscore for the ClientID property which is then used to render dataitems with ID "_crm". This way the clientside check fails.

If you remove the attribute everything works again.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try adjusting the "Skin" that is in use on the Page Management page? Try using one of the "default" skins with DNN, see if perhaps there is a jquery/javascript conflict with something in your skin/theme that is causing the JS error you're seeing.

If that happens to resolve the problem, I would start looking at your "load order" of JS files.

What version of DNN platform are you currently running on?

Comment: I will try that and report my results. The version is Evoq Content 8.5. We use our own skin and have uninstalled the default skin. But I can restore that and try.

Comment: Just checked, there is no Page Theme and no Page Container set. It still works in our test environment but not on the dev machine

Comment: There might not be a page theme set, but is it using the "site" theme?

Comment: How can I see this? Site Theme is set to our own theme. It works on one machine, doesn't on the other. Kind of weird

Comment: I've tested numerous themes and the problem still occurs

Comment: So a different machine works, are you by chance logging in with a different account on the other machine?

Comment: no same account. I've also tried a different account locally. I'm just curisous about how the prefix would be able to change if it is hardcoded in DNN?